# How can I get tmux to show me the commands I'm typing on the screen as I type them?

Tags: tmux

I've found that when I'm using tmux while presenting to a group of people, many will get confused with what I'm doing unless I use mouse mode to switch between tabs or panes.

Is there a nice way to make tmux show me the commands I'm typing on the screen (maybe in the top right) while I type them?

Thanks

I'm relatively new to tmux, so I just tried ChatGPT and it gave me this command:

`setw -g command-prompt -1`

From what I can see, this "makes the promp only accept one key press" (from the manpage) but does not achieve my goal